# 'ReporteRs' is not available

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to install a package named as "ReporteRs" but it gives me error like: "Warning in install.packages : package 'ReporteRs' is not available (for R version 3.4.4)"

My R Version is 3.4.4.
Here's my installation code;

```
cran_dir_url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ReporteRs/ReporteRs_0.8.9.tar.gz"

install.packages("ReporteRs", contriburl=cran_dir_url,
                 repos = cran_dir_url, 
                 type = 'source',
                 INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
```

Comment: There is also a new package "export" to easily export R graphs to Powerpoint, see https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html

Answer (score 8):

The package has been relaunched as `officer` (see https://github.com/davidgohel/ReporteRs). So install via:

```
install.packages("officer")
```

or the dev version via

```
devtools::install_github("davidgohel/officer")
```

Comment: There is also a new package "export" to easily export R graphs to Powerpoint, see https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html